# Getting an authenticated user's inventory via Half.com API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, inventory, ebay-api

I'm working on an Inventory Management solution that needs to interact with Half.com.  Half.com uses a subset of the eBay API referenced [here](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Development/Sites-HalfCalls.html).

The one fundamental element I cannot find for half.com is the ability to get an authenticated user's listing inventory.  I see how to modify or display listings via Product IDs but not how to actually get a list of valid Product IDs.  Since this seems to be core functionality I can only assume that I am missing something.

If you know how I should be going about this, or can point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I ran into this situation myself when developing an app that needed to do this and figured it out.  While not documented by eBay at the link you provided, the GetSellerList API does the job.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>EBAY USER AUTH TOKEN HERE</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<GranularityLevel>Fine</GranularityLevel>
<ListingType>Half</ListingType>
<StartTimeFrom>TODAYS DATE HERE</StartTimeFrom>
<StartTimeTo>119 DAYS IN THE FUTURE FROM TODAYS DATE HERE</StartTimeTo>
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetSellerListRequest>
```

The key is the ListingType being set to "Half".   The other key is that you need to take a large date range (max is 120 days for this API) to get all of the listings when they are of the half.com type.

The example XML request will return all of the inventory listed by a given seller on half.com where you have already fetched an API session token for that user.